# Stop page scroll on input

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-component

When I try to update a value in type=number or type=range, the page scrolls to the top. IS there any way to stop that from occuring?

```
<input type=number bind:value={temper} min=0 max=50>
```

I see sapper has something this --

```
<a href='path' sapper:noscroll>Path</a>
```

which supposedly stops the scrolling when link 'Path' is clicked. Anything similar for svelte 3?

thanks,
gani -

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1)?

Comment: Yes, here is the [link](https://svelte.dev/repl/466c7bb294ce4243ab21647b3a848024?version=3.44.1)

BTW, there is a bug in Svelte which will say Plotly is not defined. To get rid of the error message, you just have to either create a new line or remove line after <svelte:head...> and that seems to fix it. 
After that you can see that changing temperature causes the scrolling to top

Comment: Ok, I just made a very simplified [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/db2cb58d5c764b1687b8f74d956d9048?version=3.44.1) to see if it's a 'pure' Svelte problem and it looks like it's not. You're using 'plotly' (best to add that information and the REPL to your question) and there's a lot going on. I'd try to remove things step by step so it becomes clearer what's causing the scroll...

Comment: Looks like if the console is open the scrolling doesn't happen, but there are some errors going on 'Maximum call stack size exceeded/Uncaught (in promise)'...

Comment: That is strange, but it might be because of multiple calls to coolprop.js on AWS S3 which is a wrapper to a wasm file. If you close the browser and try again, it should go away. Regarding using plotly, I had mentioned that I'm getting error about plotly, and how to fix it. Is there another way to call plotly?

Comment: Instead of in `<svelte:head>` you can alternatively also import inside the normal script tag `import Plotly from 'plotly.js-dist';` but with that still the same errors

Comment: Thx! Very interesting I'm also seeing errors on my computer, but it worked fine on my iPhone! I did have to enter a new line to get plotly going, though. (But scrolling problem remained)

Comment: BTW, I figured what was going on with the errors. You just have to wait before trying to change anything. Loading the wasm takes time and trying to do anything before it loads, causes the REPL to barf. Also, using your suggestion on plotly worked. Now just the scrolling bit needs to be resolved/understood :)